# Execute script on remote Machine from my native iOS App. (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, libssh2

I am working on native iOS App (**SSH Client**) and I am connecting to the remote servers via SSH using **libssh2**. I want to run one script to the remote servers using SSH.

So, How to execute the script on remote server?